# Should aria-expanded attribute take the value true or string "true"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wai-aria

I am setting the aria-expanded attribute's value with jquery. I am confused whether I should do:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", true);
```

or

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
```

Should true be treated as a string or simply a javascript data type?

Answer (score 1):

We can use both way to set *aria-expanded* attribute. Both will set attribute correctly.

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
$(".dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", true);
```

Normally first option is used but we can use both.